# Avoiding OutOfMemoryError when using Logstash to index large wide JSON file in Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to find a method to efficiently index some large nested JSON files into Elasticsearch but I'm having trouble avoiding OutOfMemoryError's.

Using my less than ideal setup (Win7, 8GB RAM, spinning hard-drive) I am able to index a 5.4GB, 4.3GB and 2.3GB file from within the same .conf.  I also need to index a 27GB and 80GB file.  All of my files have approximately the same number of rows (~40,000) so the larger files have very wide rows.  Since posting [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-logstash-importing-very-large-json-files/37015) I decided to split these larger files up into < 6GB files (so the 80GB file is now split into 17 separate files).  However when I go to index just a single one of the split files I get this error:

`IndexFailedEngineException[Index failed for [subject#84142]]; nested: OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space];`

This occurs even in the smallest of these split files (~2.6GB).  Therefore I've concluded that this issue is related to how wide the rows are.  Each row in all of my documents has a nested structure like this example:

`{"id":2,"file3":[{"id":2,"time":"2094-05-18 01:28:23","event2":"RT4"} {"id":2,"time":"2094-05-18 04:23:53","event2":"W3"}]}`

With the 20+GB files there are thousands of JSON documents per row. I can't reduce the row width and maintain the structure I require though.

I have tried a number of settings to prevent the OutOfMemoryError with no luck:
`export LS_HEAP_SIZE=4g`
elasticsearch.yml: `index.merge.scheduler.max_thread_count : 1` , `index.refresh_interval : -1`

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
    "persistent" : {
        "indices.store.throttle.max_bytes_per_sec" : "1mb"
    }
}
```

How can I change the Logstash settings such that it can handle these files with large rows?  Is there a way to slow down the number of items being indexed?

Comment: i guess you need more ram or some more computers

Comment: i note that an AWS EC2 instance with 30GiB of ram is available in the early hours of the morning for under 7c an hour